# Change contact setting flood limit

Tags: 8, emails

I want to change the contact setting flood limit, but I don't find the correct place. How I change the flood limit for sent messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an interface to change this, but you can do it by importing a config file. You need to get a hold of `contact.settings.yml` file. Default looks something like this:

```
default_form: feedback
flood:
  limit: 5
  interval: 3600
user_default_enabled: true
```

You can see the flood limit and interval which you can change and then import the file using the config management system.

Answer (score 0):

With Drush, you can use `drush cedit contact.settings`.